# htaccess redirect a specific url without get variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

```
Redirect 302 /forums/blahblah.46/ /calendar/agenda
```

This redirect rule is fine, except i don't want to redirect when get variables are present in the url. Only redirect the root, not anything else

i.e. this url shouldnt toggle redirections:

```
http://www.domain.com/forums/blahblah.46/?some=var
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `mod_rewrite` for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^forums/blahblah.46/?$ /calendar/agenda [L,NC,R=302]
```

Condition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` ensures to redirect only when query string is empty.